# Tab key no longer triggers autocomplete for vim sninpmate snippets

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

after long hours of vim configuration, I found out that I broke the snipmate plugin. Hitting the tab key no longer works. Any experiences? 'Yeap I know there are million reasons why it might be broken, but was hoping others have experienced it before. So I tried this

```
:verbose map<Tab>
```

And this was what  I noticed

```
x  <Tab>       * s<C-O>:let g:snipmate_content_visual=getreg( 1 )<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
s  <Tab>       * <Esc>i<Right><C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Things seem to look fine from the verbose output. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the set paste line in my vimrc and it worked!

Comment: `set paste` should **never** be in your `~/.vimrc`.